# Debugging GridView / ObjectDataSource events

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, edititemtemplate

Ahoy!

I am using an ASP.NET GridView control bound to an ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Things" runat="server"
    TypeName="BLL.Thing"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateThing"
    OnUpdating="Things_Updating"
    OnUpdated="Things_Updated">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter
            Name="userContext"
            SessionField="UserContext"
            Type="Object" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="thing" Type="Object" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Clicking on an ImageButton control with CommandName="Update" causes the specified OnUpdating event to occur, but not the specified UpdateMethod or the OnUpdated event.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton_Save" runat="server"
        CommandName="Update"
        SkinID="Save"
        CausesValidation="false"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton_Cancel" runat="server"
        CommandName="Cancel"
        SkinID="Cancel"
        CausesValidation="false" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

The input parameters are defined in the OnUpdating event like so:

```
protected void Things_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["thing"] = _theThing;
}
```

No exception is thrown. The page just posts back with the EditItemTemplate controls still showing. I can put breakpoints all over the place, but the trail stops at the end of Things_Updating. It seems that some exception is happening which is not handled or caught by the debugger. Is there a way to open the hood and see what ASP.NET is doing (or failing to do)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `BLL.Thing.UpdateThing()` execute?  This should occur after `Things.Updating` and be easily debug-able.  Also if there is something causing an exception, that is probably it.

Edit:

Try adding the parameter in a handler for `GridView.RowUpdating` instead of `ObjectDataSource.Updating`.  That is how I usually do it.  I think you need to get the `DataSourceView` to modify the update parameters in the `ObjectDataSource`'s event.  (See: [ObjectDataSource Gridview Insert Fails W/ Empty Values Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370416/objectdatasource-gridview-insert-fails-w-empty-values-dictionary))

```
protected void gridThings_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues.Add("thing", _theThing);
}
```

Comment: Nope, the trail mysteriously ends after Things_Updating :-/

Comment: I don't think the GridView class has an OnUpdating event, but it does have a RowCommand event which I will use instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam My mistake, I meant to reference `GridView.RowUpdating`.  Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind that could cause the progress to stop right there:

1. You've handled he `GridView.RowUpdating` event as well, and set the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs.Cancel` property to true.  Something like this:

   ```
   protected void myGridView_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
   ```
2. You've done something similar in the `ObjectDataSource.Updating` event, setting the `ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs.Cancel` property to false.  Like this:

   ```
   private void myObjectDataSource_Updating(object source, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
   ```

Either of these will halt the update process, causing something like what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, partner. I have conditional logic that sets e.Cancel to true in certain circumstances, but they aren't being hit. I'm going to give up on this approach and use my own method in the RowCommand event instead.

Comment: @Adam Well shoot!  Good luck to you then =)